# String comparison logic not working as intended

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file with different times in it that looks like this:

```
 12:30 am
 4:50 PM
 6:15 A.M.
 8:09 p.m.
```

etc.

I want to parse this file for the hour, minute, and meridian. I tried using the regex `"[: ]"`, but I keep getting `IOException("Invalid meridian.")` thrown at me... an exception *I made*.

Here's some of the code:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the input file: ");
        inputFile = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the output file: ");
        outputFile = in.nextLine();

        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
        while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
            String[] vals = fileIn.nextLine().split("[: ]");
            int hours = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
            String meridian = vals[2];
            times.add(new Time(hours, minutes, meridian));
        }

        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println("Unsorted times: ");

        for (Time i: times)
            System.out.println(i);

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(90);
    }
```

And here's where the IOException was first conceived (in the Time constructor):

```
if (!(meridian.toUpperCase().equals("AM")   &&
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("A.M.") &&
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("PM")   &&
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("P.M.")))
        throw new IOException("Invalid meridian.");
```

What could be the problem? ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ

Comment: Why not just use a SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  It is never the case that it's equal to all 4 of the strings at the same time.  You want the logical-OR `||` inside your parentheses:

```
if (!(meridian.toUpperCase().equals("AM")   ||
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("A.M.") ||
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("PM")   ||
      meridian.toUpperCase().equals("P.M.")))
```

That way if it's equal to one of the expected cases, then the exception won't be thrown.

Comment: Oh wow, I was under the impression that the ! sign was distributed i.e. !(a && b) = !a && !b, but it's actually !a || !b. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes, flip the logical operator when distributing the "not": [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).